# git pull origin master not wokring

Tags: flutter, git, github, git-commit

Whenever i try to push my git that is when i use "git push -u origin master" this command
I get "error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Username/gitname' "

I tried "git pull origin master" and ran into "fatal: couldn't find remote ref master" this error
which i found here https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/error-failed-to-push-some-refs-to-how-to-fix-in-git/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+src+refspec+master+does+not+match+any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push does not work because it seems like there is no branch named "master" in your local repository. Try just `git push -u origin` (so without ref name), then Git will push will default to the current branch.
Alternatively, check the name or your current branch (`git branch`) and then do `git push -u origin <branchname>`.

Similarly, I suppose the pull does not work because the remote does not contain a branch named "master".